# My Timer is going crazy , It decrements 2 , 3 seconds when it should only 1 (Timer is being called every second)

Tags: flutter, timer, state

A very simple timer written in Flutter. But the timer's *time* is jumping from 1 to 3 , 3 to 6 (crazy) and it goes to -(minus) value when it should stop. Using *setState* to update the time.
Here is the code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Timer Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'My Timer'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void updateUI()=>setState((){});
  var timer=MyTimer();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    timer.start(updateUI);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Timer'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(timer.time.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyTimer{
  int time=10;
  
  start(Function callback){
    Timer.periodic((Duration (seconds:1)),(timer){
      time--;
      callback();
      if(time<1) timer.cancel();
    });
  }
}
```

I am building the app for windows desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting timer inside the `build()` method, meaning every time the UI is rerendered, the `start()` function is called inside `MyTimer` class.

You can try calling the `timer.start(updateUI)` inside the initState method (add it to `_MyHomePageState`), e.g:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer.start(updateUI);
}
```